# RESTful Soft Delete

Tags: rest, put

I'm trying to build a RESTful webapp wherein I utilize GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE. But I had a question about the use of DELETE in this particular app.

A bit of background first:

My webapp manages generic entities that are also managed (and, it happens, always created) in another system. So within my webapp, each entity will be stored in the database with a unique key. But the way we will be accessing them through URLs is with the unique key of the *other* system.

A simple example will make this clear, I think. Take the URL `/entity/1`. This will display information for the entity with ID 1 *in the other system*, and not my own system. In fact, IDs in my system will be completely hidden. There will be no URL scheme for accessing the entity with ID of `1` in my own system.

Alright, so now that we know how my webapp is structured, let's return to deleting those entities.

There will be a way to 'delete' entities in my system, but I put quotes around it because it won't actually be deleting them from the database. Rather, it will flag them with a property that prevents it from appearing when you go to `/entity/1`.

Because of this, I feel like I should be using `PUT` ('deleting' in this way will be idempotent), since I am, from the perspective of the data, simply setting a property.

So, the question: does the RESTful approach have fidelity to the data (in which case it is clear that I am `PUT`ing), or the representation of the data in the app (in which case it seems that I am `DELETE`ing)?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You should use `DELETE`.

What you intend to do with your data is called "soft deleting": you set a flag and avoid flagged items from appearing. This is internal to your webapp and the user doesn't have to know that you're soft deleting instead of deleting or whatever you want to do. This is why you should use the `DELETE` verb.

Comment: Yes - You should use the verb/method that describes what you want to happen. DELETE is the better choice

Comment: I concur with alestanis too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, alestanis! I've come to agree with your reasoning; I'm just waiting a few days to see if any other compelling responses in either direction appear before I accept.

Comment: I'd add that if you want the API user to be able to hide a resource, it's similar to delete but the fact you are exposing that functionality to them means you're better off using a PUT with an active/disabled/etc field.

I'm implementing this at the moment and I've now moved onto the problem of propagating the soft delete to all the relationships.

Comment: Also, if you are exposing a functionality of delete, then by any means it should only give a soft delete in the system. If we leave out an endopoint by using 'update', that would technically mean that the system doesnt at all support delete, which is not the case.

Comment: But what if you support both soft  and hard delete, how should they be differentiated?

Comment: I'm adding my 2 cents on a way to decide which pattern to use in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67382339/1491212

Comment: my 2 cents to this discussion, I believe it should depend on the use case of the api, for example, if the API provides both operations like support to hard delete the record and also like shelve/ soft delete a record that can be brought back later. Then a POST and DELETE method makes more sense to me. That way the intentions of the endpoint are very clear. If the API consumer need not worry about how data is deleted then it makes sense to have it represented by DELETE. Hope it also answers @TigranBabajanyan 's question. I agree with the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67382339/6861114

Answer (score 6):

I think there is no definitive answer. I'd rely on whether 1. the soft-delete, recover and destroy actions are an actual feature of your api OR 2. soft-delete is merely a "paranoid" database engineering pattern.

1. The "soft" deletion is transparent for the api client, in which case using the `DELETE` verb seems like the way to go

   Everything is as if the item was to be removed once and for all, but engineers want to keep it somewhere in the database
2. Api clients have the ability to recover or destroy the soft deleted resource, in which case soft deletion and recovery can use `POST` on a different action url like `/resource/:id/softdelete` and the destroy action would be the one using `DELETE`.

   Another way to go may be to use `DELETE` with no query parameter to soft delete, and add `?destroy=true` to actually destroy. But this approach seems less explicit and more prone to errors.

Answer (score 4):

> The DELETE method has very specific semantics in HTTP, which must not be overloaded
> or stretched by a REST API’s design. Specifically, an API should not distort the intended
> meaning of DELETE by mapping it to a lesser action that leaves the resource, and its URI,
> available to clients. For example, if an API wishes to provide a “soft” delete or some
> other state-changing interaction, it should employ a special controller resource and
> direct its clients to use POST instead of DELETE to interact.

***Source***: Rest-API Desgin Rule book by Mark Massé

***Suggestion***:

```
POST: /entity/1/your-soft-delete-controller-name
```