# Understanding HTTP DELETE method in a REST API

Tags: rest, http, http-delete, http-method

I wonder about the REST API structure: Is it correct to use the HTTP `DELETE` method without effectively deleting a resource on the webserver dir but in a database?

Comment: then why do you want to use `DELETE`?

Comment: REST handles resources. If you make a `DELETE` operation, there should  be at least one less resource to get over the REST interface after. Where or how this resource is persistent is none of REST's concerns

Comment: define `deleting a resource on the webserver` However you might want to use `soft deletes` that way the record still exists, it is just marked as deleted using a column `deleted`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RESTful Soft Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839114/restful-soft-delete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) defines the semantics of the HTTP `DELETE` method.

It *expresses a deletion operation on the URI mapping* (and it doesn't expect that the associated content will be actually deleted from the server). Whether the actual content will be deleted or not or whether it can be restored or not, is up to the server implementation.

See the quote below (highlights are mine):

> [**4.3.5.  DELETE**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.5)
>
> The `DELETE` method requests that the origin server remove the
> association between the target resource and its current
> functionality.  In effect, this method is similar to the `rm` command
> in UNIX: **it expresses a deletion operation on the URI mapping of the
> origin server rather than an expectation that the previously
> associated information be deleted.**
>
> **If the target resource has one or more current representations, they
> might or might not be destroyed by the origin server, and the
> associated storage might or might not be reclaimed**, depending
> entirely on the nature of the resource and its implementation by the
> origin server (which are beyond the scope of this specification).
> Likewise, other **implementation aspects of a resource might need to be
> deactivated or archived as a result of a `DELETE`**, such as database or
> gateway connections.  In general, it is assumed that the origin
> server will only allow `DELETE` on resources for which it has a
> prescribed mechanism for accomplishing the deletion. [...]